# Paginate laravel duvidas

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Transformei esse código 1 no código 2

```
1)//$palpites=DB::select("SELECT * FROM palpite  WHERE  id_u='$id'   order by id_c desc ");
   2) $palpites = DB::table('palpite')->where('id_u',$id)->orderby('id_c','desc') ->paginate(3);
```

Como transformar esse código abaixo no mesmo exemplo do 1,2?

```
$confrontos=DB::select("SELECT * FROM confrontos as c, palpite as p WHERE   p.id_u ='$id' AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM palpite WHERE c.id = p.id_c)  order by id_c desc ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia!

Na cláusula onde envolve uma sub-consulta tu deves utilizar uma Clousure (função anônima) passando a informação desejada.

Exemplo:

...

```
->where(function($q) use ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('p.*'))
          ->from('palpite')
          ->whereRaw('c.id = p.id_c');
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Após a tua explicação sobre o que devia ser retornado, minha sugestão é primeiramente tu modificar tua query, da seguinte maneira:

```
select * from conf 
inner join pal on pal.id_c = c.id 
where pal.id_u = $id;
```

Desta maneira tu consegue os mesmos resultados que tu desejas. Para realizar a paginação dessa consulta no Laravel tu deve escrever algo como:

```
$confrontos = DB::table('confrontos') 
->select('*') 
->join('palpites', 'palpites.id_confronto', '=', 'confronto.id') 
->where('palpites.id_usuario', $id) 
->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Tem como completar? estou meio inseguro em relação a este código.

Comment: Posso tentar sim. Mas eu dei um exemplo apenas da parte que envolve a sub-query. A consulta anterior tu pode te basear no exemplo que tu mesmo utilizou no item (2). Qual é a ideia principal da consulta? Tu quer retornar exatamente o que?

Comment: Os dois códigos consultam a mesma coisa(1,2)... código está correto, porém a intenção de transformar ele é para paginar! porém esse outro código é mais complexo... e eu não estou sabendo transformar!

Comment: Entendi. Então, vamos lá. A consulta que envolve uma sub-query não é necessária para realizar a paginação. Não me parece correto. No Laravel tu podes paginar simplismente assim: $table = DB::table('table')->paginate(10); e na tua view apenas renderizar da seguinte maneira: $table->render();

Comment: Lorenzo, como ficaria?

Comment: @DanEven tu precisa apenas utilizar o "paginate()" do Eloquent. Eu não entendi ainda se é a consulta com a sub-query que tu quer paginar ou a que tu escreveu no item (2). Tá confuso.

Comment: então! eu tenho o exemplo 1) que eu trasformei no 2) para poder paginar, e funciona! quero fazer a mesma coisa com o exemplo abaixo, para paginar! só que o código é mais complexo, usa referencia de duas tabelas, mas gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67005/discussion-between-lorenzo-fernandez-and-dan-even).